# Looping through specific class in view : Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have been using the following code to loop through specific classes in my subviews.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < [[self.view subviews] count]; i++) {
        if ([[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] class] == [UIButton class]) {

        }
    }
```

But i feel like there should be a better way. Could someone please help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for(UIView *v in [self.view subviews]) {
  if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this to iterate through a specific class in a view.  I find it a bit cleaner.

```
for (UIButton *button in [self.view subviews]) {
     // do whatever e.g. button.layer.cornerRadius = 11.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Alternately, you could use a block by sending the subviews array `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`.